# What's the use of GraphQL?

Tags: php, reactjs, api, graphql, backoffice

Is graphQL a superset of MySQL ? or is it a superset or a back-end language like PHP ? And is graphQL just a way to write simplest API ? Thanks for explaining me.
I don't understand what is really "GraphQL" regarding the website

Comment: https://graphql.org ... and hundreds of 'REST vs GraphQL' sites ... SO is not a learning platform

Comment: See https://www.howtographql.com/

Comment: GraphQL is a specification for a query language that can be implemented in any language. You need to document yourself a bit more so that your question is more relevant. Good questions usually bring great answer

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL is a query language for APIs, it is not a superset of MySql or PHP, GraphQL provides a complete description of the data in your API & it is runtime for fulfilling those queries for existing data.

It makes it easier to develop APIs over time and enables powerful developer tools. We can use GraphQL in the frontend as well as in the backend. we can express a description of data in GraphQL.